# Getting wifi users list

Tags: c#, winforms, wifi

I have a TP-Link wifi router (150M)
I share my wifi connection to one of friend via LAN Wire... means I just plugged in LAN wire in one of my router(Primary/Main router) port/slot and another end to my friend's router slot(Secondary).

It's working fine.

Now, I can see how many users are connect to my router(Primary)
But I can only able to see that my friend's router is connected/Online... it not shown how many user/devices are connected to his router.

I mean to say if my Secondary Router is connected to Primary Router... it must show all the users which are connected via Primary Router...

I done some coding to get list of connected users of my router; it's work fine.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lstLocal.View = View.Details;
    lstLocal.Clear();
    lstLocal.GridLines = true;
    lstLocal.FullRowSelect = true;
    lstLocal.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Aquamarine;
    lstLocal.Columns.Add("IP", 100);
    lstLocal.Columns.Add("HostName", 200);
    lstLocal.Columns.Add("MAC Address", 300);
    lstLocal.Sorting = SortOrder.Descending;
    Ping_all();   //Automate pending
}

static string NetworkGateway()
{
    string ip = null;

    foreach (NetworkInterface f in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
    {
        if (f.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
        {
            foreach (GatewayIPAddressInformation d in f.GetIPProperties().GatewayAddresses)
            {
                if(ip==null)
                ip = d.Address.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
    return ip;
}

public void Ping_all()
{
    string gate_ip = NetworkGateway();
    //Extracting and pinging all other ip's.
    string[] array = gate_ip.Split('.');

    for (int i = 0; i <= 255; i++)
    {
        string ping_var = array[0] + "." + array[1] + "." + array[2] + "." + i;
        //time in milliseconds           
        Ping(ping_var, 1, 4000);
    }
}

public void Ping(string host, int attempts, int timeout)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < attempts; i++)
    {
        new Thread(delegate()
        {
            try
            {
                System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping ping = new System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping();
                ping.PingCompleted += new PingCompletedEventHandler(PingCompleted);
                ping.SendAsync(host, timeout, host);
            }
            catch
            {
                // Do nothing and let it try again until the attempts are exausted.
                // Exceptions are thrown for normal ping failurs like address lookup
                // failed.  For this reason we are supressing errors.
            }
        }).Start();
    }
}

private void PingCompleted(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    string ip = (string)e.UserState;
    if (e.Reply != null && e.Reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
    {
        string hostname = GetHostName(ip);
        string macaddres = GetMacAddress(ip);
        string[] arr = new string[3];

        //store all three parameters to be shown on ListView
        arr[0] = ip;
        arr[1] = hostname;
        arr[2] = macaddres;

        // Logic for Ping Reply Success
        ListViewItem item;
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                item = new ListViewItem(arr);
                if (lstLocal.Items.Contains(item))
                {
                }
                else
                {
                    lstLocal.Items.Add(item);
                }
            }));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // MessageBox.Show(e.Reply.Status.ToString());
    }
}

public string GetHostName(string ipAddress)
{
    try
    {
        IPHostEntry entry = Dns.GetHostEntry(ipAddress);
        if (entry != null)
        {
            return entry.HostName;
        }
    }
    catch (SocketException)
    {
        // MessageBox.Show(e.Message.ToString());
    }
    return null;
}

//Get MAC address
public string GetMacAddress(string ipAddress)
{
    string macAddress = string.Empty;
    System.Diagnostics.Process Process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    Process.StartInfo.FileName = "arp";
    Process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-a " + ipAddress;
    Process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    Process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    Process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    Process.Start();
    string strOutput = Process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    string[] substrings = strOutput.Split('-');
    if (substrings.Length >= 8)
    {
        macAddress = substrings[3].Substring(Math.Max(0, substrings[3].Length - 2))
                 + "-" + substrings[4] + "-" + substrings[5] + "-" + substrings[6]
                 + "-" + substrings[7] + "-"
                 + substrings[8].Substring(0, 2);
        return macAddress;
    }
    else
    {
        return "My Machine";
    }
}
```

Can anybody tell me how I can get a list of Secondary's Router Users.

Comment: If your router isconnected to the wan port of your friends router, the router of your friend has its own network. To get the connections to it you will need its internal network id and subnetmask.